# How to download PDF in ionic/capacitor/vue

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor, ionic5

I have pdf in blob:

> data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xL...

How do I view this pdf file in InAppBrowser or download and view it in Chrome in Android platform?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a `<a>` tag and then trigger the download:

```js
const data = 'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xL...';

const downloadPDF = (href) => {
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = href;
  downloadLink.download = "fileName.pdf";
  downloadLink.click();
};

downloadPDF(data);
```